# Have any of the Romani communities ever had concrete criteria for membership?

Tags: anthropology

If one were to ask an Orthodox rabbi about the criteria for a person to be considered Jewish, he would probably reply along the following lines:

- One does not become Jewish simply by declaring oneself to be so.
- Any child born to a Jewish mother is Jewish automatically.
- Anyone else may, after a period of study and spiritual formation, become Jewish by being declared as such by a Jewish religious court.

I am trying to discern whether there has ever been **a similar set of criteria** for any of the manifold Romani communities.

---

I have searched, but I have yet to find any such concrete criteria. I have come across the concept of ***Romanipen***, the unwritten Romani code/philosophy/spirit, and I have read that it addresses the question of who may be considered a member of the community (see, for example, [here](https://www.cultureunplugged.com/play/4488/Romanipen--the-Gipsy-Identity)), but the actual membership criteria never seem to be spelled out.

Even the Roma's **persecutors** seem to have had a very blurry idea of who was and was not Romani. The English Parliament passed 'Egyptian' acts in 1530 and 1554, and the Scottish Parliament passed a similar act in 1609; but, despite the terrible punishments these statutes mandated - deportation or hanging - they never define what exactly makes a person an 'Egyptian'. It's a similar story with the infamous Nuremberg Laws; both Jews and Roma were classified as subhuman, but, while Jewishness was defined precisely, no corresponding definition was given for the Roma.

---

Some more specific questions for which I would like to find answers:

- Were children born to a Romani father and a non-Romani mother considered to be Romani themselves? What about for a Romani mother and a non-Romani father?
- If a given Rom or his descendants failed to keep Romani customs, could he or they lose their Romani-ness?
- Could a non-Romani acquire Romani-ness by following some set route?

Comment: This is an awesome question. IME, the rigor of an ethnic group's membership criteria is proportional to the importance they see in classifying people as either insiders or outsiders. For example, Jewish law generally forbids intermarriage, so knowing whether some person who wants to marry your child qualifies is very important. OTOH, there are no bright-line criteria between Celtic and non-Celtic people because Celtic people don't have rules requiring outsiders to be treated differently. If you think you are Celtic and other Celts seem to accept you, then you are Celtic.

Comment: @RobertColumbia 'Celtic people don't have rules requiring outsiders to be treated differently.' You've clearly never been to Glasgow! ;)